# How to format an anchor tag as a string?

Tags: javascript

this line:

```
return '<a href="javascript:SomeFunction('+ var1 + ',' + var2 + ')"; > Stars </a>';
```

renders this:

```
<a href="javascript:SomeFunction(Pure Magic,4)" ;=""> Stars </a>
```

which looks like a proper anchor tag but gives this error on clicking it:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

I am sure this error is misleading as the bracket in question is right there.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do `var1` and `var2` contain - ie what is the actual string returned?

Comment: Creating code like this invites XSS and Code Injection vulnerabilities, even when it works for the expected inputs.  The error you are experiencing is caused by the actual code, determined by `var1` and `var2`, is not what you expect it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not wrapping your first var (which seems to be a string) within quotes.

```
return '<a href="javascript:SomeFunction(\''+ var1 + '\', ' + var2 + ');" > Stars </a>';
```

---

**NOTE**: As pointed out in the comments by [Paul S.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1615483/paul-s) the semicolon should be inside the double quotes as it is part of the attribute value.

Comment: You can't use non-entity double quotes inside an attribute bound by double quotes, the first one will terminate the attribute

Comment: Yep changing them for single quotes

Comment: The semicolon should probably be in the attribute too

Comment: Thanks a lot I'm being confused :)

Answer (score 2):

As `var1` contains a string value, you need quotes around it:

```
return '<a href="javascript:SomeFunction(\'' + var1 + '\',' + var2 + ');"> Stars </a>';
```

If the string can contains characters that needs to be escaped to be in a string literal, or needs to be URI encoded, you need some more code:

```
return '<a href="javascript:' + encodeURIComponent('SomeFunction(\'' + var1.replace("\\", "\\\\").replace("'", "\\'") + '\',' + var2 + ');') + '"> Stars </a>';
```

Generating code like this is complicated, and it's easy to get it wrong. If possible you should generate elements instead, so that you can set the properties directly instead of creating code for it. Example using jQuery:

```
return $('<a>', { href: '#', text: ' Stars ' }).click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  SomeFunction(var1, var2);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have mistake in double quote at the end

```
return '<a href="javascript:SomeFunction('+ var1 + ',' + var2 + ');" > Stars </a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

As you just want to add an `<a>` with a *href*, let the browser do the escaping and encoding work for you by using a method like [`String.prototype.link`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/link)

```
' Stars '.link('javascript:SomeFunction(' + JSON.stringify(var1) + ', ' + JSON.stringify(var2) + ')');
// <a href="javascript:SomeFunction(&quot;Pure Magic&quot;, 4)"> Stars </a>
```

---

If you're running into issues like this a lot, consider whether it would be easier to switch to working with *DOM methods*, i.e.

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.addEventListener('click', SomeFunction.bind(a, var1, var2));
```

This saves you from having to write entity encodings etc to protect yourself at each level the code will be interpreted (*JavaScript*, *HTML*, *JavaScript*) and means you have more direct access over the *DOM tree* than by writing *HTML*